# Prototype .each and Effect.toggle()

Tags: prototypejs

I am new to Prototype and I have this code:

```
$$('#some_id div.some_class').each(function(e){
    Effect.toggle(e, 'slide');
})
```

What I want is to toggle with slide effect every div of .some_class inside #some_id, but instead I get only the first div of .some_class toggled. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your code looks correct.  can you post your html?

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a new Effect for each element with "new":

```
$$('#some_id div.some_class').each(function(e){
    new Effect.toggle(e, 'slide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Effect.multiple to apply an effect to an array of elements:

```
Effect.multiple($$('#some_id div.some_class'), function(el) { Effect.toggle(el,'appear'); });
```

http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/effect-multiple/

You may also want to look into Effect Queues:

http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/effect-queues/